# Can't connect to MS SQL using Active Directory Integrated Services via DatabaseLink

Tags: databaselink

We have a data lake in here that uses MS SQL Server 12.02 and connects using the active directory integrated services authentication.

The standard driver would not work

```
<< "DatabaseLink`"
 
sqlStandard = 
  SQLConnection[
   JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", 
    "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;DatabaseName=db;authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"], 
   "Name" -> "DataLake", "Catalog" -> Automatic,"Description" -> None, "ReadOnly" -> Automatic, 
   "RelativePath" -> False, "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> Automatic,"UseConnectionPool" -> Automatic];


connStandard = OpenSQLConnection[sqlStandard]

(*JDBC::error: The syntax of the connection URL 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver;DatabaseName=dw-scv-prod;authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated' is invalid.*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded the MS SQL driver from Microsoft

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

and installed it under C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\Oracle\Java

also placed the following dll driver in

[mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc_auth/8.2.2.x64)

in the same directory.

```
sqlMS = SQLConnection[
   JDBC["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;DatabaseName=dbprod;authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"], 
   "Name" -> "DataLake", "Catalog" -> Automatic, 
   "Description" -> None, "ReadOnly" -> Automatic, 
   "RelativePath" -> False, "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> Automatic, 
   "UseConnectionPool" -> Automatic];
connMS = OpenSQLConnection[sqlMS]
 
(*Success*)
```